# How to select only if the last element of an inner-join matches?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables : `processes` and `notes`. Each note is linked to a process. A process have several notes (one to many relationship). Notes also have a creation date.

I want to select each process whose last note contains a certain text (say 'some content'), but ONLY if this note is the last created one for the process.

For example :

processes table:

```
id | name
----------
42 | 'foo'
```

notes table:

```
content       | creation_date | process_id
-------------------------------------------
'note1'       | '09/13'       | 42
'note1'       | '09/14'       | 42
'some_content'| '09/15'       | 42
```

The `process_id` field in `notes` is a foreign key. In this example, the 'foo' process should be selected by my query.

If a new note is added, the `notes` tables becomes something like this:

```
content       | creation_date | process_id
-------------------------------------------
'note1'       | '09/13'       | 42
'note1'       | '09/14'       | 42
'some_content'| '09/15'       | 42
'note4'       | '09/16'       | 42
```

In this case the 'foo' process should not be selected, because the last note content is not 'some_content' anymore.

Is it possible to do such a thing in a single query?

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: you want the join to work for note 1 and some content and not for note 4 ? why is that ?

Comment: what is the pattern here, since some_content is also different than note 1 where you do want the join to work ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE for your two tables. And, what is supposed to happen on 1-Jan-2022?

Comment: Are you using MySQL > 8 by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is aggregation:

```
select p.id, p.name
from processes p join
     notes n
     on n.process_id = p.id
group by p.id, p.name
having max(n.creation_date) = max(case when n.note like '%some_content%' then n.creation_date end);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated sub query like so:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM processes
WHERE (
    SELECT content
    FROM notes
    WHERE notes.process_id = processes.id
    ORDER BY creation_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) = 'some_content'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another method simply uses `exists`

```
select * 
from processes p
where exists (
    select * from notes n
    where n.process_id=p.id 
        and n.content='some_content' 
        and n.creation_date=(select Max(creation_date) from notes)
)
```